# Spring MVC. XML и Annotations конфигурации

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Могу в одном spring mvc проекте иметь место оба вида конфигураций? И через xml и через джава классы с аннотациями ?

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно. Если bootstrap приложения делаете через Java Config, то XML можно подгружать через аннотацию `@ImportResource`.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml")
public class WebConfig {
    // ...
}
```

Если наоборот, bootstrap приложения у вас через XML, то стандартный `component-scan` подтягивает конфигурацию на аннотациях.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package.to.scan"/>
```